# What happens if a possessed body dies when possessed by a demon?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Does the demon die too?
Is she/he cast out?  If so, does he go back to her/his cover or go straight to Demonic form?

I looked in the following books for a rule on the matter:
DtD, FoH, CoD

None of them seem to have a definitive rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a subjective answer; the Exploit doesn't specify what happens if the "host body" should dies, and no later material has revisited this Exploit.

I'll also preference this by saying my interpretation of Possession is that it essentially allows a Demon to treat any random person as a Sleeve Integrator (the victim just doesn't get the benefits)

As such, and looking to the fact that "While possessing the target, none of the demon's Covers are anywhere to be found" implies that, for all purposes, this person's body *is* the Demon's current body:

DtD, page 43.

> If a demon were to cling to a single human identity for long enough, he would age and become infirm. ... a demon whose chose to [stay in a body aging to death] could eventually die of natural causes, just like any human.

Bracket text mine, for emphasis.

What happens to you if the body you are in dies? *You die.*

Or, to put it in a lighter tone, "If you die in the Matrix [read: someone else's body], you die in real life."

Comment: But this is not the standard result for Spirits and Ghosts who possess mortals - they don't die when the mortal dies, do they?

Comment: Ephemeral beings can't use the "Possession" Exploit - they instead apply the "Possessed" Condition via the "Possess" Manifestation. Thematically similar, but different rules may apply. This answer is predicated on the idea that the Cover-esque verbiage of the Exploit dominates its implications.